# UINavigationController weird transparency behaviour when presenting

Tags: swift, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios13

I'm experiencing a weird glitch with the transparent navigation controller. When presenting a view controller with a `UIImage` at the top of the navigation controller: at first presents half of its background blur with a dark section, and half with a clear one; and after a very short moment it changes for a full dark background. As shown in the gif:

[image]

The `UIImage` displayed is mostly white, the borders are very close to pure white. So the grey color does not make much sense (less sense makes the rapid change).

I did disable `extend edges under top bar` in the Storyboard for the presented view controller. So the image is not hidden behind the Navigation Controller. With this option enabled the glitch does not appear, but I don't want to hide part of the image.

Disabling the transparency, solves my problem, but I'd like to be able to keep the transparency effect.

Edit: I did notice the "grey effect" also makes the navigation controller opaque. But only for that view, when going back, is transparent again.

> Xcode 11, Swift 5, iOS 13.2, iPhone XS.

---

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I would check your navigationController views' background colour.  Looks like it is transparent (which is the default) might help

Comment: @DavidLintin setting a color on the view attenuates the problem, but the glitch is still there... Is that what you meant?

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the problem.

I didn't want the `UIScrollView` to bounce on top so I used this code:

```swift
extension ProblematicViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    /// Prevent bounce at top
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
            scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Which meant the ViewController's `Adjust Scroll View Insets` were overwrite (I think). So my scroll view did lay under the `UINavigationController`, to prevent this from happening, I did disable `Extend Edges: Under Top Bars`, so the root `UIView` containing the `UIScrollView` was not covered by the `UINavigationController`. So the transparency effect could never happen because the view was never under the top bar. [More about `Adjust Scroll View Insets` on this post](https://medium.com/@wailord/the-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-rabbit-hole-b9153a769ce9) (helped me to find the problem).

Removing those lines and enabling `Adjust Scroll View Insets` and `Extend Edges: Under Top Bars`, solves the glitch problem, but the `UIViewController` does not have the "prevent bounce on top" behaviour that I wanted.

This kinda explains the weird behaviour of the `UINavigationController` because the SO has to calculate a transparency over nothing, but is sill strange, the transparency effect is calculated when the `ProblematicViewController` is fully presented, and not on `viewDidLoad()` or another view's life cycle before is shown to the user, so the transition is smooth, even when nothing lays behind the effect.

Comment: It’s good that you fixed it. But this answer in no way grows out of the info present in the question.

Comment: @matt I don't get the downvote. It's caused by `Extend Edges: Under Top Bars ` being disabled (in the question), happens just by disabling it. Does not answer the question on why the glitch happens, and so is not the accepted answer.

My answer, has all the information on why I think it does that, just if someone has  the same problem, isn't a solution, a workaround maybe.

If you (or someone) answered just "looks there is nothing behind the `UINavigationController`, add something behind so it has something to calculate the effect" would have help a lot.